# How do pandas Rolling objects work?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, cython

**Edit:** I condensed this question given that it was probably too involved to begin with.  The meat of the question is in bold below.

I'd like to know more about the object that is actually created when using [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas.DataFrame.rolling) or [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
print(type(df.rolling))
<class 'pandas.core.window.Rolling'>
```

Some background: consider the oft-used alternative with `np.as_strided`.  This code snippet itself isn't important, but its result is my reference point in asking this question.

```
def rwindows(a, window):
    if a.ndim == 1:
        a = a.reshape(-1, 1)
    shape = a.shape[0] - window + 1, window, a.shape[-1]
    strides = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return np.squeeze(windows)
```

Here `rwindows` will take a 1d or 2d `ndarray` and build rolling "blocks" equal to the specified window size (as below).  **How does a `.rolling` object compare to the `ndarray` output below?**  Is it an iterator, with certain attributes stored for each block?  Or something else entirely?  I've tried playing around with tab completion on the object with attributes/methods such as `__dict__` and `_get_index()` and they're not telling me much.  I've also seen a [`_create_blocks`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/window.py#L132) method in pandas--does it at all resemble the `strided` method?

```
# as_strided version

a = np.arange(5)
print(rwindows(a, 3))           # 1d input
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]

b = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
print(rwindows(b, 4))           # 2d input
[[[0 1]
  [2 3]
  [4 5]
  [6 7]]

 [[2 3]
  [4 5]
  [6 7]
  [8 9]]]
```

### Part 2, extra credit

Using the NumPy approach above (OLS implementation [here](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance/blob/master/ols.py)) is necessitated by the fact that `func` within [pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) must

> produce a single value from an ndarray input *args and **kwargs are
>   passed to the function

So the argument can't be another rolling object.  I.e.

```
def prod(a, b):
    return a * b
df.rolling(3).apply(prod, args=((df + 2).rolling(3),))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Rolling'
```

So this is really from where my question above stems.  Why is it that the passed function must use a NumPy array and produce a single scalar value, and what does this have to do with the layout of a `.rolling` object?

Comment: I think this question is too broad and should be more specific without branching into multiple questions

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the source code in order to get into the nitty gritty of what rolling does. In particular I suggest you have a look at the `rolling` functions in [generic.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L6188-L6195) and [window.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/window.py#L2044-L2052). From there you can have a look at the [`Window` class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/window.py#L357-L681) which is used if you specify a window type or the default [`Rolling` class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/window.py#L1057-L1287). The last one inherits from `_Rolling_and_Expanding` and ultimately `_Rolling` and `_Window`.

That said, I'll give my two cents: Pandas' whole rolling mechanism relies on the numpy function [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). In particular it is used [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window.py#L804) in pandas. It is used in conjunction with the [`windows.pyx`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx) cython module. In goes your series, out comes the aggregated rolling window. For typical aggregation functions it handles them for you efficiently, but for custom ones (using `apply()`) it uses a [`roll_generic()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx#L1412) in `windows.pyx`.

The rolling function in pandas operates on pandas data frame columns independently. It is not a [python iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), and is lazy loaded, meaning nothing is computed until you apply an aggregation function to it. The functions which actually apply the rolling window of data aren't used until right before an aggregation is done.

A source of confusion might be that you're thinking of the rolling object as a dataframe. (You have named the rolling object `df` in your last code snippet). It really isn't. It is an object which can produce dataframes by applying aggregations over the window logic it houses.

The lambda you are supplying is applied for each cell of your new dataframe. It takes a window backwards (along each column) in your old dataframe, and it aggregates it to one single cell in the new dataframe. The aggregation can be things like `sum`, `mean`, something custom you've made, etc., over some window size, say 3. Here are some examples:

```
a = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
df.rolling(3).mean().dropna()
```

... which can also be done by:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(np.mean).dropna()
```

... and produces:

```
     a
2  3.0
3  6.0
4  9.0
```

(The first column is the index value and can be ignored here, and for the next examples.)

Notice how we supplied an existing numpy aggregation function. That's the idea. We're supposed to be able to supply anything we want as long as it conforms to what aggregation functions do, i.e., take a vector of values and produce a single value from it. Here is another one where we create a custom aggregation function, in this case the L2 norm of the window:

```
df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(x.dot(x))).dropna()
```

if you're not familiar with lambda functions this is the same as:

```
def euclidean_dist(x):
    return np.sqrt(x.dot(x))

df.rolling(3).apply(euclidean_dist).dropna()
```

... yielding:

```
          a
2  2.236068
3  3.741657
4  5.385165
```

Just to make sure, we can manually check that `np.sqrt(0**2 + 1**2 + 2**2)` is indeed `2.236068`.

[In your original edit, in the] last code snippet, your code is probably failing early than you expect. It is failing before the invocation of `df.apply(...)` You are trying to add a rolling object named `df` to the number 2 before it is passed to `df.apply(...)`. The rolling object isn't something you do operations on. The aggregation function you have supplied also doesn't conform to an aggregation function in general. The `a` is a list with the values of a window, `b` would be a constant extra parameter you pass in. It can be a rolling object if you want, but it wouldn't typically be something you would like to do. To make it more clear, here is something which is similar to what you were doing in your original edit but works:

```
a = np.arange(8)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
n = 4
rol = df.rolling(n)

def prod(window_list, constant_rol):
    return window_list.dot(constant_rol.sum().dropna().head(n))

rol.apply(prod, args=(rol,)).dropna()

# [92.0, 140.0, 188.0, 236.0, 284.0]
```

It is a contrived example, but I'm showing it to make the point that you can pass in whatever you want as a constant, even the rolling object you are using itself. The dynamic part is the first argument `a` in your case or `window_list` in my case. All defined windows, in the form of individual lists, are passed into that function one by one.

Based on your followup comments this might be what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 3
a = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])

def keep(window, windows):
    windows.append(window.copy())
    return window[-1]

windows = list()
df['a'].rolling(n).apply(keep, args=(windows,))
df = df.tail(n)
df['a_window'] = windows
```

which adds arrays/vectors to each rolling block thus producing:

```
   a         a_window
2  2  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
3  3  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
4  4  [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Note that it only works if you do it on a column at a time. If you want to do some math on the window before you store it away in `keep` that is fine too.

That said, without more input on exactly what you are trying to achieve it is hard to construct an example which suits your needs.

If your ultimate goal is to create a dataframe of lagging variables then I'd go for using real columns using `shift()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(5)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
for i in range(1,3):
    df['a-%s' % i] = df['a'].shift(i)

df.dropna()
```

... giving:

```
   a  a-1  a-2
2  2  1.0  0.0
3  3  2.0  1.0
4  4  3.0  2.0
```

(There might be some more beautiful way of doing it, but it gets the job done.)

Regarding your variable `b` in your first code snippet, remember DataFrames in pandas aren't typically handled as tensors of arbitrary dimensions/object. You can probably stuff whatever you want into it, but ultimately strings, time objects, ints and floats is what is expected. That might be the reasons the designers of pandas haven't bothered with allowing rolling aggregation to non-scalar values. It doesn't even seem like a simple string is allowed as output of the aggregation function.

Anyway, I hope this answer some of your questions. If not let me know, and I'll try to help you out in the comments, or an update.

---

Final note on the `_create_blocks()` function of rolling objects.

The `_create_blocks()` function handles the reindexing and binning when you use the `freq` argument of `rolling`.

If you use freq with, say, weeks such that `freq=W`:

```
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(50)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df['a'], 'D')
blocks, obj, index = df.rolling(4, freq='W')._create_blocks(how=None)
for b in blocks:
    print(b)
```

... then we get the binned (not rolling) original data week-by-week:

```
               a
a               
2016-01-03   2.0
2016-01-10   9.0
2016-01-17  16.0
2016-01-24  23.0
2016-01-31  30.0
2016-02-07  37.0
2016-02-14  44.0
2016-02-21   NaN
```

Notice that this isn't the output of the aggregated rolling. This is simply the new blocks it works on. After this. We do an aggregation like `sum` and get:

```
                a
a                
2016-01-03    NaN
2016-01-10    NaN
2016-01-17    NaN
2016-01-24   50.0
2016-01-31   78.0
2016-02-07  106.0
2016-02-14  134.0
2016-02-21    NaN
```

... which checks out with a test summation: 50 = 2 + 9 + 16 + 23.

If you don't use `freq` as an argument it simply returns the original data structure:

```
import pandas as pd
a = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
blocks, obj, index = df.rolling(3)._create_blocks(how=None)

for b in blocks:
    print(b)
```

... which produces ...

```
            a
a            
2016-01-01  0
2016-01-02  1
2016-01-03  2
2016-01-04  3
2016-01-05  4
```

... and is used for rolling window aggregation.

Comment: I'll make an update later when you've got time to review and have some questions. A note on the update you did: It doesn't fail early anymore, that's good, but now it fails inside the aggregation function. You're now passing `(df + 2).rolling(3)`, which is a rolling object, into the aggregation function, as a constant, which then attempts to do arithmetics (*) between window data (float64 ndarray) and the new rolling object. Rolling objects are just helper objects, you're not supposed to do operations on them, other than aggregations. It's a `df` object factory, if that makes sense.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you actually want to do. Could you give a data example of input and expected output. Given `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`: Do you want to produce something like `[[0, 1, 2] * 2, [1, 2, 3] * 3, [2, 3, 4] * 4]`? If so you can do it by `def prod(a): return myagg(a * a[-1])` = the window times the last element of the window. But as I've said, you still have to aggregate over the window, i.e., replace `myagg` with sum, or mean, or something. The output of rolling is always a single value. With `sum` instead of `myagg` you get `[sum(0,2,4), sum(3,6,9), sum(8,12,16)]` = `[6, 18, 36]`.

Comment: Your section about passing a `rolling` object in `args=(rol,)` is helpful, but unfortunately most of your answer reaffirmed things I already knew.  But what I'd ultimately like to get to is to produce a column vector (and then transpose it) or a row vector, for each rolling block, rather than a single scalar.  But it looks like there's no getting around that directly.

Comment: @BradSolomon The vector "for each rolling block", aka. the window, is the argument `a` in your `prod(a, b)` aggregation function. Ask yourself what is the next step. What do you want to do with the inner vectors you are producing using rolling? Typically that would be to aggregate it some way. If you simply want to hold on to them, then you can use my `shift(...)` example. There you get to keep the window/vector as rows, with columns `a`, `a-1`, and `a-2` in the example.

Comment: @BradSolomon I've added an example to the answer where you get to keep the window/vectors in each cell of dataframe produced by the rolling object.

Comment: Thanks, one more question that I don't feel has been addressed.  What is the result of `_create_blocks`?  This is the core of my question.  For instance, if I use `blocks, obj, index == df.rolling(window=2)._create_blocks(how=None)`, the resulting `blocks` is not what I expect.  (It seems to return just the original `df`.)  Because `blocks` is looped over in the [code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/window.py#L824) to which you linked, I'd expect it to contain the collection of different "window" blocks.

Comment: Yeah. It does indeed have a deceptive name. All it does is handle reindexing and binning when you use the deprecated `freq` argument of `rolling()`, in addition to selecting the column for aggregation when using the `on` argument of `rolling()`. I'll add a note on it at the end of the answer.

Comment: @BradSolomon I found the heart of the generic rolling window which uses `apply()`. It is a cython function named [`roll_generic()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/window.pyx#L1412). There is nothing good looking about it, i.e., it is pretty low level code. It slides across your series using indexes and applies your aggregation function to the windows.