# Pandas Rolling Apply with Scipy FindPeaks function: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am seeking help using scipy function [Find_Peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) within pandas.Series.Rolling.apply functionality. I am throwing TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars in each of my attempts and I can't understand 1.) Why 2.) How to write properly

My end goal: As of a perspective date, find the historical peaks in the signal.

The find_peaks function identifies peaks inside a signal based on the peak properties. I am using the prominence methodology helpful example from Mathworks ->  [prominence methodology](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/prominence.html)

The function itself takes in a one-dimensional array and returns a tuple(peaks:ndarray, properties:dict).

Desired output:

```
x = np.ones((12,))
x[3] = 10
x[7] = 10
x[11] = 10
x = pd.Series(x)
x.rolling(4).apply(lambda x: find_peaks(x,prominence=.2)[0])

0      []
1      []
2      []
3      [3]
4      [3]
5      [3]
6      [3]
7      [3,7]
8      [3,7]
9      [3,7]
10     [3,7]
11     [3,7]
dtype: float64
```

Attemps/Error Messages:

```
x.rolling(4).apply(lambda x: find_peaks(x,prominence=.2)[0])
```

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

from [SO36680402](http://The%20error%20%22only%20length-1%20arrays%20can%20be%20converted%20to%20Python%20scalars%22%20is%20raised%20when%20the%20function%20expects%20a%20single%20value%20but%20you%20pass%20an%20array%20instead.) This error occurs The error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" is raised when the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead.

But, [SO45254174](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254174/how-do-pandas-rolling-objects-work) appears to contradict this TypeError with this example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 3
a = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])

def keep(window, windows):
    windows.append(window.copy())
    return window[-1]

windows = list()
df['a'].rolling(n).apply(keep, args=(windows,))
df = df.tail(n)
df['a_window'] = windows
```

which adds arrays/vectors to each rolling block thus producing:

```
   a         a_window
2  2  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
3  3  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
4  4  [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

First Attempt:

```
x.rolling(4).apply(lambda x: find_peaks(x,prominence=.2)[0])
```

Error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Second Attempt:

```
def _find_peaks(array,prominence=.2):
   peaks,_ = find_peaks(array,prominence=prominence)
   return np.empty((0,0)) if peaks.shape[0]==0 else peaks

x.rolling(4).apply(_find_peaks)
```

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

**Any thoughts on how to write and why I am throwing errors would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is work with an array instead, and use the `wlen` parameter in [`find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) to set a window length instead of using [`pd.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences):

> **wlen : int or float, optional:**  A window length in samples that optionally limits the evaluated area for each peak to a subset of x. The peak is always placed in the middle of the window therefore the given length is rounded up to the next odd integer. This parameter can speed up the calculation

So instead, you could do:

```
find_peaks(x.values, prominence=0.2, wlen=4)

(array([3, 7], dtype=int64),
 {'left_bases': array([2, 6], dtype=int64),
  'prominences': array([9., 9.]),
  'right_bases': array([4, 8], dtype=int64)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Nixon for your thoughts. I actually really liked the prominence option as the way to define my peaks. I found two solutions to the problem, not exactly in the same format as my desired output.

Here is what I came up with. Solution 1 appears faster, but solution 2 feels easier to read to me.

[image]

[image]

**Solution 1** : [As_Strided Rolling Window](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)

numpy's as_strided function makes creating rolling windows very fast.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = np.ones((12,))
x[3] = 10
x[7] = 10
x[11] = 10

frames_example_1 = pd.DataFrame(stride_tricks.as_strided(x,shape=(len(x)-7+1,7),strides=(8,8)))

peaks = frames_example_1.apply(find_peaks,axis=1,prominence=0.2).apply(lambda x: x[0])

aligned_peaks = np.arange(1,7).reshape(6,1) + \ 
pd.DataFrame(peaks.tolist(),index=np.arange(6,12),columns=['first_peak','second_peak'])
aligned_peaks.index.name = 'perspective date'
```

[image: Output Date]

**Solution 2**:Numpy Fancy Indexing  [Fancy Indexing Explained](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html)
Still leveraging numpy as I could not figure out a way to accomplish the original code through pandas.

```
window = 7 
frames, frame_length = len(x) - window +1, window 

indexer = np.tile(np.arange(frame_length),frames).reshape(frames,frame_length) + \
 np.arange(frames).reshape(frames,1)


 peaks = pd.DataFrame(x[indexer],index=np.arange(6,12)).apply(find_peaks,axis=1,prominence=0.2).apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Then the same procedure as before:

```
aligned_peaks = np.arange(1,7).reshape(6,1) + pd.DataFrame(peaks.tolist(),index=np.arange(6,12),columns=['first_peak','second_peak'])
aligned_peaks.index.name = 'perspective date'
```

[image]