# Pandas, call custom function on rolling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function `my_function(data)` that takes in `data` a Python array (or Numpy serie) and returns an integer.

I could feed to this function a column from a Pandas dataframe and I would get the `my_function` of the entire series.

Now I would like to do that but on a rolling basis.

`my_function(data['column'].rolling(30))` simply won't work because the function wants an array. Same goes for `data['column'].rolling(30).my_function`.

What's the syntactically correct way to do this? Is it possible? Or do I have to do that manually?

If I have to loop over the dataframe by myself, is there anything I can use so that each iteration gives me an arbitrary number of rows at a time (lets say 30)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html):

```
data['column'].rolling(30).apply(my_function)
```

Also help [How do pandas Rolling objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45254174).