# How to use rolling in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the code below:

```
# Resample, interpolate and inspect ozone data here
data = data.resample('D').interpolate()
data.info()
# Create the rolling window
***rolling = data.rolling(360)['Ozone']

# Insert the rolling quantiles to the monthly returns
data['q10'] = rolling.quantile(.1)
data['q50'] = rolling.quantile(.5)
data['q90'] = rolling.quantile(.9)
# Plot the data
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

For the starred line (***), I was wondering, can I use the following instead?

`data['Ozone'].rolling(360)`

Why is the following expression `False`?

`data.rolling(360)['Ozone']==data['Ozone'].rolling(360)`

What are their differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `data.rolling(360)['Ozone']` & `data['Ozone'].rolling(360)` can be used interchangeably, but they should be compared after using an aggregation method, such as `.mean`, and `pandas.DataFrame.equal` should be used to make the comparison.
- `.rolling` methods require a `window`, or number of observations used for the calculation. The values in the `window`, `10` in the example below, are filled with `NaN`.
- [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)
- [`pandas.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)
- `df.rolling(10)['A'])` & `df['A'].rolling(10)` are a `pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling` type, which won't compare.

  - See the documentation and [How do pandas Rolling objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254174) for more details about how `.rolling` works.
- [Pandas: Window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html) - functions

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test data and dataframe
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(20, 1)), columns=['A'])

# this is pandas.DataFrame.rolling with a column selection
df.rolling(10)['A']
[out]:
Rolling [window=10,center=False,axis=0]

# this is pandas.Series.rolling
df['A'].rolling(10)
[out]:
Rolling [window=10,center=False,axis=0]

# see that the type is the same, pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling
type(df.rolling(10)['A']) == type(df['A'].rolling(10))
[out]:
True

# the two implementations evaluate as False, when compared
df.rolling(10)['A'] == df['A'].rolling(10)
[out]:
False
```

- The objects can be compared once an aggregation method is used.

  - Aggregating `.mean`, we can see the values used for the `window` are `NaN`.
- `df.rolling(10)['A'].mean()` & `df['A'].rolling(10).mean()` are both `pandas.core.series.Series` type, which can be compared.

```py
df.rolling(10)['A'].mean()
[out]:
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9     12.3
10    12.2
11    12.1
12    12.3
13    11.1
14    12.1
15    12.3
16    12.3
17    12.0
18    11.5
19    11.9
Name: A, dtype: float64

df['A'].rolling(10).mean()
[out]:
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5      NaN
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9     12.3
10    12.2
11    12.1
12    12.3
13    11.1
14    12.1
15    12.3
16    12.3
17    12.0
18    11.5
19    11.9
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

- They do not evaluate the same because `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`. Essentially, they are the same, but when comparing the two with `==`, the rows with `NaN` evaluate as `False`.
- Using [`pandas.DataFrame.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) however, treats NaNs in the same location as equal.

```py
# row by row evaluation
df.rolling(10)['A'].mean() == df['A'].rolling(10).mean()
[out]:
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
16     True
17     True
18     True
19     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

# overall comparison
all(df.rolling(10)['A'].mean() == df['A'].rolling(10).mean())
[out]:
False

# using pandas.DataFrame.equals
df.rolling(10)['A'].mean().equals(df['A'].rolling(10).mean())
[out]:
True
```